# Require.js not loading Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, requirejs

So I have some generated JavaScript (from TypeScript):

```
define(["require", "exports", "three", "jquery", "./test"], function (require, exports, THREE, jQuery, Test) {
var Main = (function () {
    function Main() {
        this.container = jQuery('#test');
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
...
```

This ends up with an error in the browser (on the last line of above):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Scene' of undefined
```

Interestingly jQuery has no problems; it's as if Three.js is simply not being loaded.

Require config:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "src",
    paths: {
        "main": "../main",
        "test": "../test",
        "three": "../three/three",
        "sizzle": "/src/sizzle/dist/sizzle"
    }
});
```

jQuery is in the 'js/src' folder, whereas Three.js is at 'js/three/three.js' (Express is being used so the js folder is hidden to the browser, and it doesn't seem to make any difference if I move three.js to the src folder). Sizzle is sitting on it's own because it was causing errors from being in a subfolder inside src.

Am I missing anything obvious about this? I have no leads

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### From r72 onwards

From r72 onwards, three does call `define`. So you should not set a `shim`. If you do **not** have code that relies on `THREE` being available in the global space, you're done.

However, **if there is** code that relies on `THREE` being available in the global space, that's a problem because, as a well-behaved AMD module, `THREE` no longer just leaks to the global space. For code that needs `THREE` in the global space, you can just create a module like this which you can put just before your call to `requirejs.config`:

```
define("three-glue", ["three"], function (three) {
    window.THREE = three;
    return three;
});
```

Your RequireJS configuration should contain this map:

```
map: {
  '*': {
    three: 'three-glue'
  },
  'three-glue': {
    three: 'three'
  }
}
```

This tells RequireJS "wherever `three` is required, load `three-glue` instead, but when `three` is required in `three-glue` load `three`."

All together:

```
define("three-glue", ["three"], function (three) {
    window.THREE = three;
    return three;
});

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "src",
    paths: {
        "main": "../main",
        "test": "../test",
        "three": "../three/three",
        "sizzle": "/src/sizzle/dist/sizzle"
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            three: 'three-glue'
        },
        'three-glue': {
            three: 'three'
        }
    }
});
```

(Technical note: r72 actually still performed the leak to the global space, and some versions after it do. The latest released version at the time of editing this answer (r83) does **not** leak to the global space by itself. I've not examined every version between r72 and r83 to check when the change was made. Using the code above with an old AMD-compliant version that does the leak is safe. It just results in unnecessary code.)

#### For r71 and earlier

If [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/eee231960882f6f3b6113405f524956145148146/build/three.js) is any guide, three does not call `define`. So you need a `shim` for it if you want it to have a value when you require it as a module. Something like this:

```
shim: {
    three: {
        exports: 'THREE'
    }
}
```

Based on the config you have in your question:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "src",
    paths: {
        "main": "../main",
        "test": "../test",
        "three": "../three/three",
        "sizzle": "/src/sizzle/dist/sizzle"
    },
    shim: {
        three: {
            exports: 'THREE'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! If you don't mind asking, how would I go about implementing this? I'm not too experienced with shims

Comment: Sorry, I get what you mean now, I'll give it a go!

Comment: I was editing my answer as you were writing your second comment. :)

Comment: Beautiful, that's fixed it! :D Marked as answer, thanks very much!

Comment: What should I do if I want to use a OrbitControls?