# THREE is 'undefined' when require.js loading Three.js (revision=80)

Tags: three.js, requirejs

```
require.config({
baseUrl:'resource',
paths:{
    'three': 'lib/threeJS/three.min',
    'OrbitControls': 'lib/threeJS/OrbitControls'
},
shim:{
    'OrbitControls': {
        deps: ['three'],
        exports:'OrbitControls'
    }
}    
});
require(['OrbitControls'],function (OrbitControls) {
});
```

My test code is shown above and when I debug this code, the console output

> THREE is 'OrbitControls.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined(…)'.

However, there is no problem with **Three.js(revision=75)**. So I review the source code of three.js, and I find some differences. The most important one is the different moduling method. Three.js(revision = 80) starts from:

```
(function (global, factory) {
typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
(factory((global.THREE = global.THREE || {})));
}(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';
```

So anyone could tell me how to add this version of three.js with require.js?    In addition, my require.js is ver.  2.1.19

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Require.js not loading Three.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358323/require-js-not-loading-three-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct after appending this code before using it:

```
define('three', ['../js/lib/threejs/three.82.min'], function ( THREE ) { window.THREE = THREE; return THREE; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define just path of js on **path:** i think you have written js name. please change it and then load js using it's name in shim tag.

also refer code from [hear](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/load-external-js-asynchronously-using-requirejs)

Comment: it doesn't work. But it's correct after appending this code:

define('three', ['../js/lib/threejs/three.82.min'], function ( THREE ) {
    window.THREE = THREE;
    return THREE;
});